# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header' when subclass LoginView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to try a custom login on django and want to process some form data before login. I went out to this:

```
class mylogin(auth_views.LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("datas :D!", form.cleaned_data['password'])
        super().form_valid(form)
```

All the other things should remain the ones of the LoginView.
So, in my urls.py I have:

```
path('login/', views.mylogin.as_view(template_name='public/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Error, when i try to log in is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Comment: You should **`return`** the result of `super().form_valid(form)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`FormMixin.form_valid`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) function is supposed to *return* a `HttpResponse` object in case the form is valid.

Here you *call* the `super().form_valid(form)` function, but you do not return the `HttpResponse` it generates, you thus should add a `return` statement:

```
class mylogin(auth_views.LoginView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("datas :D!", form.cleaned_data['password'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You can of course also decide to construct a `HttpResponse` in your `form_valid` function, or for example first "post-process" the response before returning it, but regardless, the contract is that `form_valid` should return a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thanks for the explainations! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of calling super.

```
return super().form_valid(form)
```